# Shell extract jest output

Tags: shell, sed, jestjs

I want to write a shell script to extract values from my jest coverage report for further calculations

I have the following output:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 50% ( 25/50 )
Branches     : 25% ( 10/40 )
Functions    : 50% ( 10/20 )
Lines        : 33.8% ( 25/50 )
================================================================================
```

Now I want to extract the "40" value from "10/40" from the "Branches" line.

Currently my script only consists of the command to get the output

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
COVERAGE_RAW=$(jest --coverage --coverageReporters="text-summary" )
```

So far I tried to extract the word "Branches" using

```
VAR1=$(echo "$COVERAGE_RAW" | sed 's/Branches/\1/' )
echo "$VAR"
```

but the result is empty

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code you tried in your question, which is highly encouraged on Stack Overflow. There is nothing wrong or right in efforts as we all are here to learn, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in `awk`, please try following code.

```
echo "$COVERAGE_RAW" | awk -F'/| ' '/Branches/{print $(NF-1)}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, passing `COVERAGE_RAW` variable's output as an standard input to `awk` code. In `awk` code, setting field separator as (space OR |), then searching keyword `Branches` in each line, if line contains it then print 2nd last column value.

***NOTE:*** In case you have `Barnches` only once in your file then you could try following, a bit better than above, `echo "$COVERAGE_RAW" | awk -F'/| ' '/Branches/{print $(NF-1);exit}'`

Comment: How would the script look like, if I wanted to extract the number value "10/40" from the "Branches" line ? My first attempt was to capture anything so I started with "Branches" instead of what I really wanted.

Comment: @PhuAnhTuanNguyen, I had this answer because of `Now I want to extract the "40" value from "10/40" from the "Branches" line.` do you want only 40 out of it?

Comment: yes, I want the 40 out out it. I read the post wrong.   `echo "$COVERAGE_RAW" | awk -F'/| ' '/Branches/{print $(NF-1);exit}'`. Was the solution, thanks!